# Google sign in integration into android library project

Tags: android, google-signin

i'm trying to integrate google sign in into my app, i've followed all the steps from developers site and it works perfectly on standalone app, BUT, i need to create an android library project where i'm going to have an activity, which must have google sign in button. So i include this library project into an application project and then extend that activity in it to reuse base sign in activity. Ok, now about a problem, when i run this project on device with Android 5.1 it works as it should, but on KitKat it fails. I've tried on different devices, the same story. I've tried with different Google Play Services versions, the same. Can anyone point me to what i'm doing wrong, please ?

Comment: Solved , but don't know the actual reason at this moment. The issue was because in the Manifest for the the activity which was extending SignIn activity android:launchMode was set to "singleInstance", changed it to "singleTask" and now it works.